# How can I use a different sentence structure every so often

Tags: grammar

Instead of saying "you told me to call him when you are back" (note that here both 'you' is the same person ) can I say "you said that call him when I am back". In both can you also tell me that using "you are/were back" and "when I am/was back" okay?

And here "Last time I called here at the HR department someone said that I would be notified of any developments on my CV" is it necessary to say "someone said that **you** would be notified..."

Thanks for giving it a thought.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is 'You told me to call him when you **were** back'.

If you were going to use 'I', meaning the other person, in the second part of the sentence you would have to put it in direct speech quotation marks e.g. *You said 'Call him when I am back'*.

Again, as regards the HR department you have a choice between saying 'someone said I would be notified', but if you want to report what the person actually said you would need to put 'you will be notified' in quotation marks. Note that in this case the conditional 'would' would not be used.

Of course if you are speaking you do not normally employ quotation marks, although if you want to stress that you are quoting someone, the normal way would be to say. 'I was told, quote, you will be notified, unquote'.